# How to generate permanent Selenium Grid 4 url link/ export link to a global variable?

Tags: selenium

I want to run tests on a selenium grid network existing inside of containers. For that I need to pass the selenium hub url to the driver.

The problem is that the selenium hub url is always different. It used to be that the selenium grid had the same url from session to session, for example "https://localhost:4444/wd/hub", but now the url has the ip address part that keeps changing: http://100.00.0.0:4444, where 100.00.0.0 is the variable part.

How can I make the url stay the same from session to session?
Or how to export the url into a varuable?
Either solution would solve my problem.

The yml file I use to create selenium grid

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  e2e:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    command: bash run_test_page.sh

    depends_on:
      - 'selenium-hub'
      - 'selenium-1'
      - 'selenium-2'

  selenium-1:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    shm_size: '2gb'
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-2:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    shm_size: '2gb'
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    expose:
      - 4444
```

The output from selenium hub

```
selenium-hub_1  | 2022-05-01 12:13:44,867 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium-grid-hub.conf" during parsing
selenium-hub_1  | 2022-05-01 12:13:44,871 INFO supervisord started with pid 7
selenium-hub_1  | 2022-05-01 12:13:45,874 INFO spawned: 'selenium-grid-hub' with pid 9
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:46.589 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
selenium-hub_1  | 2022-05-01 12:13:46,593 INFO success: selenium-grid-hub entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:46.598 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:47.162 INFO [BoundZmqEventBus.<init>] - XPUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4442, advertising as tcp://100.00.0.0:4442], XSUB binding to [binding to tcp://*:4443, advertising as tcp://100.00.0.0:4443]
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:47.377 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Connecting to tcp://100.00.0.0:4442 and tcp://100.00.0.0:4443
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:47.571 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Sockets created
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:48.573 INFO [UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>] - Event bus ready
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:52.113 INFO [Hub.execute] - Started Selenium Hub 4.1.4 (revision 535d840ee2): http://100.00.0.0:4444
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:53.888 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: id, relative, name
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:55.296 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching Node 79566d8f-468c-4a70-8af4-c969aa9bbd21 (uri: http://100.00.0.0:5555) from DOWN to UP
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:55.299 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node 79566d8f-468c-4a70-8af4-c969aa9bbd21 at http://100.00.0.0:5555. Health check every 120s
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:55.331 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: id, relative, name
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:55.430 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session request received by the Distributor: 
selenium-hub_1  |  [Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--window-size=1920,1080, --headless], extensions: []}, pageLoadStrategy: normal}]
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:55.742 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching Node b43fc442-971c-4ef3-be4a-4c6a439ca386 (uri: http://100.00.0.0:5555) from DOWN to UP
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:55.746 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node b43fc442-971c-4ef3-be4a-4c6a439ca386 at http://100.00.0.0:5555. Health check every 120s
selenium-hub_1  | 12:13:55.761 INFO [LocalDistributor.newSession] - Session request received by the Distributor: 
selenium-hub_1  |  [Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--window-size=1920,1080, --headless], extensions: []}, pageLoadStrategy: normal}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. The right way to address the corect container was by calling it by name

Instaead of http://100.00.0.0:4444 it should be http://selenium-hub:4444

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).